# how to add Data to datagrid inside datagrid on button click from two different table

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have one datagrid which display employee info. On selection of row of this grid I want to expand it to another grid which show department info ragarding that employee.

I added a datagrid in rowdetailstemplate of the outer datagrid. And want to bind data to it on selection of outer row.
Can anybody please tell me how to do that, as I am new to silverlight and not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the inner grid to a property on the DataItem from the outer grid:

```
<asp:DataGrid id="innerGrid" runat="server" DataSource="<%# ((OuterObject)Container.DataItem).DataSourceForInnerGrid %>">...</asp:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hello josh,thanks for reply but I want solution in silverlight only . sorry for adding incorrect info

Comment: I see. I'm sure someone else can be of better assistance then!